# バッチファイルにドラッグ＆ドロップして、テキストファイルであれば名前を変更したい

Tags: batch-file

バッチファイル初心者です。最近バッチファイルを駆使すれば面倒な作業が簡略化できることを知って勉強中です。
バッチファイルに任意のファイル名をドラッグ&ドロップすると、そのファイル名を引数として受け取り実行されることを知りました。

環境:
デスクトップ上のバッチファイル (echo.bat) にテキストファイル (sample.txt) を
ドラッグ&ドロップ

```
@echo off
REM %1が受け取る引数
echo %1
pause
```

->C:\Users\username\Desktop\sample.txt

これを利用すれば、ドラッグ&ドロップして名前を (sample.txt) に変更できます。

```
rename %1 smaple.txt
```

ここまでは確認しているのですが、条件分岐の場合、なぜかうまくいきません。
（D&Dされたファイルが.txtであればsample.txtに変更)

```
@echo off
REM ドラッグアンドドロップでファイル名を変更
REM .txtであればsample.txtに名前を変更

if %1 == *.txt (
    rename %1 sample.txt
) else (
    echo textファイルではありません
)

pause
```

なぜかテキストファイルをドラッグしても `else()` 部分に飛んでしまいます。
いろいろ試しましたがわからなく、詳しい方おられましたらご指南のほど
お願いいただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

皆さま微妙にズレていたり複雑にしているような？

`echo %~n1`だとファイル名部分だけであって、拡張子が含まれません。
拡張子を含めて`find`するには`echo %1`でしょう。

そして環境変数にセットして後ろ4文字を切り出すよりは、単純に`if`の文をこちらにすればよいのでは？

```
if /I "%~x1" == ".txt" (
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうですね、これでできれば一番良いですね・・・。参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 2):

```
if %1 == *.txt (
    rename %1 sample.txt
) else (
echo textファイルではありません
)
```

を下記に変えてみてください。

```
echo %~n1 | find ".txt" 1>nul
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (
rename %1 sample.txt
) else (
echo textファイルではありません
)
```

これは文字列の中に.txtが含まれるかどうかのチェックをしています。
従いまして、拡張子で無い場所に.txtが含まれる場合もヒットします。
もっと厳密に行うためには拡張子とファイル名を分離し、拡張子だけを比較の対象にします。

参考
https://karat5i.blogspot.com/2015/02/blog-post_25.html
https://orangeclover.hatenablog.com/entry/20101004/1286120668

Comment: ありがとうございます！ヒットしたかどうかをERRORLEVELで受け取るということですね。ご参考になりました。

Answer (score 1):

```
if %1 == *.txt (
```

上記を下記のように書き換えて[末尾4文字を切り出せば](https://www.upken.jp/kb/kZwpzAqblKfZDjtMXuWuwioeExKNdE.html)拡張子と比較できます。
ちなみにif文の/Iオプションで拡張子の大文字と小文字を区別しないようにしています。[参照](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12713419)

```
set fullpath=%1
if /I "%fullpath:~-4%" == ".txt" (
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！後ろを切り取って比較すればいいということですね。とすると、ワイルドカードは比較に使えないということなのでしょうね。ご参考にさせていただきました。